# JS: Remove itme completely from object

Tags: javascript

I can't remove an itme completely froman object.
I tried:

```
    function randomKey(obj) {
var ret;
var c = 0;
for (var key in obj)
    if (Math.random() < 1/++c)
       ret = key;
return ret;
}

while(aCountryNames.length > 0){
        randomValue = randomKey(aCountryNames);
        alert(randomValue); // 42x
        delete aCountryNames[randomValue];
    }
```

I have used an extra var to accomplish this:

```
var i = 42;
    while(i > 0){
        randomValue = randomKey(aCountryNames);
        alert(randomValue); // 42x
        delete aCountryNames[randomValue];
        i--;
    }
```

The first while ends up with "undefined" alerts.

The object is:

```
var aCountryNames = {   
Alaska: 'Alaska',
NorthWestTerritory: 'North West Territory',
Alberta: 'Alberta',
Ontario: 'Ontario',
Greenland: 'Greenland',
etc.
```

After selecting an item (no problem with selecting, but for testing i use alert), i want to completely remove it from the object,so my first while-loop will finish when there are no items left anymore.

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Comment: `aCountryNames` is an `Object` and does not have a `.length` property, so in your first example, `while(aCountryNames.length > 0)`, you're checking `undefined > 0` which is always `false`.

Comment: Are you just trying to iterate through the keys of `aCountryNames` in a random order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Noah Freitas* has pointed out, an *Object* has no *length* property.

You should replace

```
aCountryNames.length
```

for

```
Object.keys(aCountryNames).length
```

Maybe you want to have a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5223/5247200) post about calculating the length of an object.

EDIT:

Here I leave you the snippet:

```js
var aCountryNames = {   
 Alaska: 'Alaska',
 NorthWestTerritory: 'North West Territory',
 Alberta: 'Alberta',
 Ontario: 'Ontario',
 Greenland: 'Greenland'
}

function randomKey(obj) {
 var ret;
 var c = 0;
 for (var key in obj)
     if (Math.random() < 1/++c)
         ret = key;
 return ret;
}

while(Object.keys(aCountryNames).length > 0){
        randomValue = randomKey(aCountryNames);
        delete aCountryNames[randomValue];
        alert(randomValue + '; there are ' + Object.keys(aCountryNames).length + ' countries left.');
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you!! especially because of the simplicity and the provided link! This solution works like a champ:) (and i understand it too...)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code :

```
var data = { a:"a", b:"b" };
delete data["a"];
```

And it worked, the attribute `a` has been deleted. 
I think you can't remove an item from an object by an index, for example : `delete data[0]`

You have to indicate the name of the attribute you want to delete.

Comment: i already did that by delete aCountryNames[randomValue]; it does not COMPLETELY  remove the item. it makes its property falase or something like that (according other posts on this site)

Comment: correction: i do use that part of course. My problem was the misunderstanding of object.length

Answer (score 1):

As [JeanMel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5249363/jeanmel) pointed out you can't delete an item by referencing a numerical index like you would with an array. You'll need to delete the item using it's key.

If you're trying to delete a random item from the object you could do the something similar to the following:

```
function randomItem(obj) {
  var result,
    count = 0;
  for (var prop in obj)
    if (Math.random() < 1/++count)
       result = prop;
  return result;
}

var aCountryNames = {   
  Alaska: 'Alaska',
  NorthWestTerritory: 'North West Territory',
  Alberta: 'Alberta',
  Ontario: 'Ontario',
  Greenland: 'Greenland'
  // Additional items
}

delete aCountryNames[randomItem(aCountryNames)];
```

The `randomItem()` function will return a random key from the object. Using `delete aCountryNames[randomItem(aCountryNames)]` will delete the item from `aCountryNames`.

Comment: thank you for your answer/time. It is almost the same solution as the accepted one. I already accepted David's answer, so yours i will flag as a useful one.

Comment: I need to be a bit faster next time, ha.